# How to set the first user's data id to 1 by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

I've 2 model, `User` and `Client` with the following relationship.

- User `has_many :clients`
- Client `belongs_to :user`

How can I make all the registered users have their first :client_id => "1", by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want all new users to default to the first client. You don't want to set a default id number, what you want to do is set it to the `id` of the first `Client` in your `clients` table.

So, in your `users_controller#new` action, all you have to do is set the `client_id` field to the `id` of the first client, like so:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  ...

  def new
    @user = User.new(:client_id => Client.first.id)
  end

end
```

This makes it so that when the new `User` record is saved, unless the user has explicitly changed the value themselves, it will always point to the first `Client` record in the database.

The reason you don't want to default it to `1` is because if you do, and you ever destroy that client from the table, then a `client_id` of `1` will point to a non-existent record, and your relationships will break for all new users after that happens. Even if you think that situation isn't going to happen, it's better to write your code in such a way that it can handle this situation, than to think it would never happen.

Comment: Thanks for your help Normalocity.

Comment: But how can I do the same thing for multiple child models Let's say for `User has_many :clients, :services`

Comment: You mean, when you're creating the `Services`? You just need to specify a default when you're creating them. If you're `.build` 'ing those new models, you'll need to iterate through all the new objects in a loop, and manually set the proper `[model]_id` fields.

Comment: That is, when you instantiate those new objects, whether that be through `.new` or `.build` or whatever, *that* is when (before saving the records to the DB) that it's probably easiest to set the associated ID fields. If that isn't convenient, when you can also set child `[model]_id` fields in a `before_save`, `after_save` or similar callback method on any ActiveRecord ancestor.

Comment: Reference to ActiveRecords callbacks, with examples: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html